# How to check if an IP is already stored in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, ip

I have this feedback form I made, but I need a bit of help. I want to stop people from posting feedbacks if they already did with the same ip, which is stored in a database. Here is the code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i');
    $checkIp = mysql_query("SELECT ip from comments WHERE ip = '$ip'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($checkIp) > 0) {
        echo "Only 1 feedback per IP allowed!";
        $IP = mysql_fetch_array($checkIp);
        print_r($IP);
    }
    if($name){
        if($email){
            if($comment){
                if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (id, name, email, comment, ip, datetime) VALUES ('','$name','$email','$comment','$ip','$datetime')");
                }
                else                        
                    echo "The email address is invalid!<br><br>";
            }
            else
                echo "You haven't entered any comment!<br><br>";
        }
        else
            echo "You haven't entered an email address!<br><br>";
    }
    else
        echo "You haven't entered your name!<br><br>";  
}
```

I tried to have a go myself, but failed (you can see at the top I tried some functions), can someone please tell me how to do it?

Comment: *don't* use IP, its not unique per human

Comment: Also, dont use mysql_* functions as they are official deprecated!, look into [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Just set a `unique` constraint on that field in the table if you only want one.

Comment: **WARNING**: This is terrifyingly insecure because those parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into the query: it creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using PDO or `mysqli_` with prepared statements rather than `mysql_` since its deprecated and due to be removed.  Also, if you really want IP address to be unique in this table, you should set a `unique` constraint on the field.

But probably you could get this code working as far as this point (for about 90-98% of cases) simply by adding an `exit;` in the if-statement where you are checking the number of rows:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($checkIp) > 0) {
    echo "Only 1 feedback per IP allowed!";
    $IP = mysql_fetch_array($checkIp);
    print_r($IP);
    exit; //stop execution here so nothing else happens
}
```

The code will be open to SQL injection, however, if you continue with `mysql_`, and it won't be as straightforward and will leave open a technical possibility of somehow ending up with more than one of the same IP in the database.

For example, if two requests came in at once and both read the database as not having the IP yet, then both inserted. With a contraint in the table, that wouldn't happen because the database server would be managing the constraint itself.